# Backup Multiple Networked Computer's Hard Drives, As Images, And All To A Single Server?

Tags: disk-image, deployment, acronis-trueimage, norton-ghost

Is it possible to backup several networked PCs hard drive's as images, and save the images to a server PC at the same time? I know that it's usual to dump one image to all PCs on the network, this is just the reverse.

Would Norton Ghost, or Acronis True Image allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Norton ghostcast server, you can select "create image" which will then clone the image of the one you are using, you can then save it to the server.